# Como criar uma alias para executar multiplos comandos com o git?

Tags: git, bash, mingw

Gostaria de saber como criar um alias para o git que execute os seguintes comandos:

- git add (todos os arquivos modificados)
- git commit (incluindo uma mensagem)
- git push

Tentei a seguinte configuração no gitconfig:

```
[alias]
   upl = !git add -A && git commit -m "$2" && git push origin master
```

Eu gostaria de utilizar a alias passando um parâmetro pra mensagem

```
git upl "cabecalho alterado"
```

Contudo dá erro na hora de fazer o commit, parece que não está correta essa forma de passar o parâmetro da mensagem pra alias

Mensagem de erro recebida

> ```
> cpd@INFORMATICA-01 MINGW64 /c/wamp/www/alura_git/curso_git (master)
> $ git upl "teste"
> error: switch `m' requires a value usage: git commit [<options>] [--] <pathspec>...
> ```

Comment: Qual o erro que é retornado?

Comment: Se vc quer adicionar todos os arquivos alterados pode trocar o git add -A por git commit -am nao? (É o que eu uso, não é a resposta pra pergunta mas melhoraria seu alias)

Comment: @Wilker erro adicionado

Comment: Bash? Power shell? CMD?

Comment: @jbueno estou utilizando o bash em ambiente windows

Comment: pelo que parece o problema está no `&&` depois do `$2` (sem o push depois do commit funciona), não sei dizer o porque, mas pode trocar o seu `$2` por `${1}` que vai funcionar.

Comment: Tente trocar o $2 por $1

Comment: @Pliavi tentei ```upl = !git add -A && git commit -m ${2} && git push origin master``` e retornou: ```error: switch `m' requires a value usage: git commit [<options>] [--] <pathspec>``` ... é o mesmo erro que já vinha dando

Comment: Usando `${1}` não `${2}`, assim como dito pelo @Wilker, apenas `$1` também deve funcionar.

Comment: Essa mensagem de erro parece ser referente  a tentar passar uma mensagem de erro vazia para o commit.  O valor -m é para especificaram mensagem de commit. O valor $2 pega o segundo argumento. No seu caso, vc precisa pegar o primeiro. Que seria o $1.

Comment: To na rua agora, pelo celular é horrível. Senão eu tentaria ajudar de uma forma melhor.

Comment: Só uma correção ali em cima. Mensagem de **commit** vazia* e não mensagem de erro vazia.

Comment: Testei trocar $2 por $1, ao que indica o commit funcionou, mas parece que há um problema na hora de sincronizar com o repositório remoto: ```$ git upl "teste0011"
[master c084230] teste0011
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
error: src refspec teste0011 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs  to 'https://github.com/[omitido]/curso_git.git'```

Comment: talvez tenha que fazer um pull e rebase antes

Comment: Com relação ao novo erro. Parece ser um problema com a brach, ele diz que não possui a branch teste0011. Vc possui mais de uma branch nesse repositório?

Comment: Tenho mais de uma branch sim, mas teste0011 não é uma branch, e sim a mensagem que deveria ser criada para o commit

Comment: Vc já testou este alias para uma branch única? A sua branch local está na branch master?
As soluções achei [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202284/error-src-refspec-does-not-match-any) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn) se referem a algum problema relacionado a branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema utilizando uma function e criando o alias pelo proprio console

```
git config --global alias.upl '!func(){ git add -A && git commit -m "$1" && git push -q; }; func'
```

Answer (score 0):

O Erro

> ```
> cpd@INFORMATICA-01 MINGW64 /c/wamp/www/alura_git/curso_git (master) $
> git upl "teste" error: switch `m' requires a value usage: git commit
> [<options>] [--] <pathspec>...
> ```

é referente a tentar passar uma **mensagem de commit vazia** para o commit. O parâmetro `-m` especifica a mensagem de commit. Ao passar o valor `$2` no trecho

> ...`commit -m`**`"$2"`**...

é passado o segundo argumento como parâmetro para `-m` que neste caso não existe. No seu caso, vc precisa pegar o primeiro argumento de

> `upl "cabecalho alterado"`

para isto, deve utilizar o valor **`$1`**, ficando assim

```
[alias]
   upl = !git add -A && git commit -m "$1" && git push origin master
```

Comment: Testei e retorna o mesmo erro do seu ultimo comentário na pergunta